# Can You Note the Notes?

Tags: cipher, music

This is what happened to Jack and Dave.

[image]

If you were Jack and Dave, what would you do?

Comment: If I were Jack and Dave, and Jack and Dave were sharing a music stand, and that stand had a pencil, that pencil would write "- 3 -" above the group of last three black notes

Comment: Disclaimer: I used an online notation writer to get this score.

Comment: Thank you for a tantalizing puzzle, I'll stop trying to decode the frequencies. Almost had something going with abRAcaDAbRa too.

Comment: What was the intended answer, if you're OK revealing it now that one has been selected?

Comment: @question_asker I was thinking of mchoy25's answer, but hmmn's was even better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would

> run the other way for a(a) bee(b), they see(c) a(a) bee(b) see(c) a(a) beeeeeeeeee(b)

Answer (score 15):

Just to show what can happen when important ciphers get into the wrong hands,
a partial decryption suggests that
if Jack and Dave were me, what they would do is look for a lawyer.

> [image]

What were Jack and Dave thinking!, entering dance bars with A minor.
Time to face the music.
Apologies to anyone unfamiliar, or too familiar, with music theory,
and to the original intent of a yet-undeciphered interesting puzzle.

Comment: THIS IS AMAZING.

Comment: I had a comment here once, but I had noticed all these things but hadn't managed to put them into this kind of narrative. Whether or not it's the intended answer, I love it.

Comment: Totally not what I had in mind... But I'm accepting it now. This answer beats my intended one hands down. Good work.

Comment: @LN6595 Please post your intended answer too.

Comment: @manshu mchoy25 already got my intended answer. But this one is fantastic.

Answer (score 5):

If we look at the notes, they are

> abca bcab

We note that

> The second bar has 5 beats, contradicting the common time (4 4)
>  in the first bar. I therefore assume that the bar separates words

This leads me to think that

> This is a cryptogram for "seas ease"

And if I were Jack and/or Dave I might

> Up anchor and sail away. Or something nautical like that.

Comment: Presumably the minim in the second bar is significant.